# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool error

Tags: php

i dont know whats wrong please help?  4 error message from while loop from assigning db data to arrray

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','project_nlt');
$qry = "select * 
        from useri_nfo 
        where skills='$skill' 
        order by u_id ASC";
if ($row = $conn->query($qry)) {
    $numrow = $row->num_rows;
    $name = array($numrow);
    $profile_img=array($numrow);
    $skills = array($numrow);
    $address = array($numrow);
    $i = 0;
    echo $numrow;
    while ($r = $row->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) && $i < $numrow) {
        echo $r;
        $name[$i] = $r['user_name'];
        $profile_img[$i] = $r['dp'];
        $skills[$i] = $r['skills'];
        $address[$i] = $r['address'];
        echo $name[$i];
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're getting error messages, it would make sense to tell us what they are.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli

Comment: Also **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: `&& $i < $numrow` should be unnecessary. The while will stop after the last row found by fetch_array anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you do not need to initialize arrays. PHP makes array usage extreemly simple

While loops will stop when a false is returned from the fetch, so no limit on rowcount is needed.

So amend the code to

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','project_nlt');
$qry = "select * 
        from useri_nfo 
        where skills='$skill' 
        order by u_id ASC";
if ($row = $conn->query($qry)) {
    while ($r = $row->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //echo $r; you cannot echo an array, try `var_dump() or print_r()

        $name[]         = $r['user_name'];
        $profile_img[]  = $r['dp'];
        $skills[]       = $r['skills'];
        $address[]      = $r['address'];
    }
}
```

> Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

So this should really be coded as

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','project_nlt');
$qry = "select * 
        from useri_nfo 
        where skills = ?  
        order by u_id ASC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $skills)
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt-<get_reslt();

while ($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //echo $r; you cannot echo an array, try `var_dump() or print_r()

    $name[]         = $r['user_name'];
    $profile_img[]  = $r['dp'];
    $skills[]       = $r['skills'];
    $address[]      = $r['address'];
}
```